# Send keys malfunctions for non English keyboards

Tags: batch-file, keyboard, sendkeys

I have the following code which visits specific site and enters a username (takes it from %USERNAME%).

It works fine as far as the keyboard is set to English, however, if a keyboard is set to another language it doesn't work properly.

Is there some way to change keyboard input language from a batch file or fix this problem the other way?

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start chrome -new-window --incognito "https://servicedesk.sa.gov.ge/"
rem the script only works if the application in question is the active window. Set a timer to wait for it to load!
timeout /t 3
rem use the tab key to move the cursor to the login and password inputs. Most htmls interact nicely with the tab key being pressed to access quick links.

rem now you can have it send the actual username/password to input box
%SendKeys% "%USERNAME%"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"

goto :EOF


@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: I would have thought it obvious, what you need to do is add some code to determine the current users keyboard language and adjust things accordingly. Please do not post code which is not exhibiting a specific issue, then expect someone to provide you with the solution or methodology, to bolt onto it when you've shown no attempt at doing the work yourself. Your question is off topic because it is a direct code request.

Comment: It is pretty specific actually, I have provided code which works well as far as the keyboard is English and malfunctions when the keyboard is non-English, all I'm trying to figure is what causes it and if there is some sort of simple solution to fix it.

Comment: Can you tell us which line isn't working, so that we can help you to fix it?  Also, why are you not using it more like this? `%SendKeys% "%UserName%{TAB}"` or `%SendKeys% "%UserName%{ENTER}"`. I ask because you appear to be using your first sendkeys line to send only a text string, not a keystroke!

Comment: This is a more low level way https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/06/simulates-printscreen-key-sendkeys.html. Remember it sends KEYS not characters.

Comment: Problem is here - %SendKeys% "%USERNAME%". It works fine as far as input keyboard language is set to English, but if input language is something else it starts to type different weird symbols, characters, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, Windows doesn't support this feature, I have tried to find an answer on superuser as well, but there is no existing solution for this yet.